# Android HTTPGet syntax misunderstanding, need help for interpreting it with GSON

Tags: java, android, http, get, gson

I'm trying to create a project that uses the API of my school.

Firstly, here is the response I recieve when I call a GET command from my API:

```
Get projects
/projects GET

Response
[
    {
        "title": "Project1",
        "num": "1",
        "registered": 1,
        "type_acti": "Project"
    },
    {
        "title": "Project2",
        "num": "2",
        "registered": 1,
        "type_acti": "Project"
    },
    {
        "title": "Project3",
        "num": "3",
        "registered": 1,
        "type_acti": "Project"
    }
]
```

Gson automatically parse my "fileData" string into classes. FileData is the string that contains the full response of my request. Don't worry about fileData, the String I recieive is 100% good, it works on other requests.

I told GSON to parse the String in the CreateGetProjects class.

**GSONTest.java**

```
public class GSONTest {
    public static void start() throws JSONException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String fileData = NextActivity.getStr();
        Log.e("Bug1", "Here it crashes :( ");
        CreateGetProjects emp1 = gson.fromJson(fileData, CreateGetProjects.class);
        Log.e("Bug1", "After the crash!");
    }
}
```

I interpreted the response this way: A List "ResponsesProjects" that stores the data into private members (Title, registered, etc...)

**CreateGetProjects.java**

```
public class CreateGetProjects {
    List<ResponsesProjects> responses;

    public List<ResponsesProjects> getResponses() {
        return responses;
    }

    public void setResponses(List<ResponsesProjects> responses) {
        this.responses = responses;
    }
}
```

**ResponsesProjects.java**

```
public class ResponsesProjects {
    private String title;
    private String num;
    private int registered;
    private String type_acti;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    public void setRegistered(int registered) {
        this.registered= registered;
    }
}
```

I think my error is about the interpretation of my GET response. As you can see on the logcat:

**Error.logcat**

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
                atcom.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
```

The interesting line, in my opinion, is **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $**.

So the problem comes from, probably, **CreateGetProjects.java**. I think it doesn't like this:
    List responses;
It expects something else, and I don't know what. I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
List<List<ResponsesProjects>> responses;
```

I need your help to discover what GSON expects, I'm new to GSON.

What do you think should I replace instead of my List "ResponsesProjects"

Thanks.

Comment: get rid of your `CreateGetProjects` class, and use `List<ResponsesProjects> res = gson.fromJson(fileData, new TypeToken<List<ResponsesProjects>>(){}.getType());`

Comment: this is because your json is an array, which Gson can only deserialize in a list of items.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. brb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try directly giving GSON a `List<ResponsesProjects>` instead of a `CreateGetProjects`: the first really is a *list* (so GSON will expect an array), whereas the second one is an *object* containing a single attribute, which is a list.

Or you could add `{}` around the request response, to wrap it into a single Json object

Comment: I used njzk2's answer:
get rid of your CreateGetProjects class, and use List<ResponsesProjects> res = gson.fromJson(fileData, new TypeToken<List<ResponsesProjects>>(){}.getType());